# "Right" way to handle C6386 in Visual C++ (buffer overrun)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I've got a code snippet that triggers a buffer overrun warning:

```
void foo(unsigned int m, int n, unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    unsigned int a[50][50];
    memset(a, 0, 50*50*sizeof(unsigned int));

    unsigned char odd = (x + y) % 2;
    
    for (int dummy = 0; dummy < n; ++dummy)
    {}

    for (int row = 0; row < m; ++row) {
        for (int col = (odd+row+1)%2; col < n; col += 2)
                a[row][col] = 0;
    }
}
```

The line that triggers the warning is `a[row][col] = 0;` where it believes `col` can go negative.  The warning goes away if I do any of the following:

- include `&& col >= 0` in the for statement (which adds an unnecessary check to a loop, since in the real code I've already checked variable bounds and know I'll never overflow)
- delete the dummy `for` loop in the middle of the code snippet (weird, I know, and in the real code that "dummy" loop is doing actual work)
- Change `dummy` to a size_t (weird, not related to the loop with the warning)
- Change `n` to an `unsigned int` (again, weird, not related to the loop in question)
- remove the `odd` variable from the `col` initializer (which would make the code incorrect)
- use a #pragma to ignore the issue (which I generally prefer to avoid)

Things that don't work:

- Check anywhere above the for loop for ranges that could lead to an overflow (I tried range checks for `m`, `n`, `x`, `y`, and even `odd`).
- Change `col` to an unsigned type like size_t, or do any type of unsigned casting

None of the workarounds leave me feeling warm and fuzzy. I've seen warnings like these quite a bit lately, often with quirky dependencies on unrelated bits of code like the dummy `for` loop seen here, and almost never exposing a real issue. Is there a best practice to avoiding this type of warning?

Comment: How to guarantee that the array with size 50*50 is enough to hold value m*n? It's better to use a `vector::vector` here.

Comment: probably it's not related to `col` but `row` because `row < m` is an unsigned comparison where `row` is converted to unsigned

Comment: It is just a warning but it is giving good advice. According to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6386?view=msvc-160):This warning indicates that the writable extent of the specified buffer might be smaller than the index used to write to it. This can cause buffer overrun.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. It seems like the warning generator is both buggy (different behavior depending on whether unrelated code is present) and limited in its ability to accurately detect variable bounds, leading to extraneous warnings. Not a big deal, but I know some shops require warning-free code. Warnings about buffer overruns that you know can never happen can lead to reworking code into less efficient, less readable, and more error prone variations just to keep the compiler happy.